# ERPNext local install LDAP login throws User with email: None does not exist in the system

Tags: ldap, erpnext

installed and using ERPNext on local Ubuntu 20.0 vm successfully. So decided to play with LDAP and the settings also validated and saved with out any issue. but when i tried to login via ldap on erpnext this error is popping out.

> frappe.exceptions.ValidationError: User with email: None does not
> exist in the system. Please ask 'System Administrator' to create the
> user for you.

installed apps are
ERPNext: v14.x.x-develop () (develop)
Frappe Framework: v15.x.x-develop () (develop)
Frappe HR: v15.0.0-dev (develop)
ldap is in a windows server 2019 vm ports are open through firewall
there are only 3 users in ldap when i tried to login through them this error occurs.
any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to find the issue, after looking at the console of erpnext login page this error

> 8090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090434, comment: AcceptSecurityContext
> error, data 533, v4f7c

was thrown by the frappe app. And cross referencing with [ldaperr](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)
this link was able to deduce the issue. The user in the ldap system was not enabled. So the error was popping out. Using `Enable-ADAccount -Identity 'Test'` on ldap server powershell i was able to enable the user , and eventually logged in to the system.

Thanks